# Como agregar hojas de Css/Js de forma dinámica [Plugin-Wordpress] -- add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', ...)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, plugin

estoy intentando crear un plugin de Wordpress con el que necesito crear páginas Css y Js de forma dinámica, es decir utilizando una consulta de una base de datos que me cargue los nombre de los archivos y genere de forma automática las hojas css/js.
Si lo hago a mano una a una no me da ningún problema con este código:

```
function agregar_hojas_estilos_css_js(){
    wp_register_style( "nombre-hoja", plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)."nombre-hoja");
    wp_enqueue_style("nombre-hoja");
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'agregar_hojas_estilos_css_js)');
```

De esta forma no hay ningún problema, pero la cosa es que tengo que hacerlo a mano y quiero automatizar la tarea.
Si intento pasar el nombre del archivo como un parámetro para la función

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','agregar_hojas_estilos_css_js');
```

ya no me funciona esa línea de código.
He intentado de esta forma pero no funciona.

```
function agregar_hojas_estilos_css_js($name){
    wp_register_style( $name, plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).$name);
    wp_enqueue_style($name);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'agregar_hojas_estilos_css_js)');
```

Alguien sabe como hacerlo? Si me puede echar una mano se lo agradezco.
Saludos !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he conseguido crear funciones utilizando - Funciones anónimas.
Para ello he creado una clase, la cual el método constructor recibe dos parámetros (nombre, tipo).
Quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
Class pages_css_js{
    
    private $fname  = "";
    private $tipo = "";

    function __construct($name,$tipo){
        $this->fname = $name;
        $this->tipo = $tipo;
    }

    function create_pages_css_js(){
        if($this->tipo == "css"){
            $func = function(){
                wp_register_style($this->fname, plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).$this->fname);
                wp_enqueue_style($this->fname);
            };
        }else if($this->tipo == "js"){
            $func = function(){
                wp_register_script($this->fname, plugin_dir_url(__FILE__). $this->fname, array('jquery'), '1', false );
                wp_enqueue_script($this->fname);
            };
        }
        return $func;
    }
}
```

Después de crear la clase, en el archivo principal del plugin he agregado el fichero mediante **require_once "ruta/nombre-fichero"** y por último he creado un bucle que reciba todos los datos de una petición a la base de datos.

```
for($e = 0; $e < count($files); $e++){
        $hoja = new pages_css_js($files[$e]->nombre, $files[$e]->tipo);
        $func = $hoja->create_pages_css_js();
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', $func);
    }
```

Espero que os sirva de ayuda, saludos !